# One database to load data from through multiple tableviews

Tags: database, ios5, storyboard

I've tried to get this app going but I don't know how to go about it. I have tried googling for days getting a good answer but to no avail. Therefor I turn to you.

I want to have a typical database (sql or core data) with all data collected. Then display first criteria in a tableview, pass data to next tableview, and in the third tableview display cells depending on the two choices made previously (like: where (x=1 & y=2) then display cells ). Finally get a detailview where I can load optional data from the database.

Any which way you can help or point me in any direction would be great.

//KeLLoGsX

Answer (score 0):

[RayWenderlich Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) has a number of tutorials that might apply.

More specifically, when a user selects a row in a view use the prepareForSegue method to set a property on the new view indicating the selection so you can taylor the new view accordingly. For example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editTemplate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        self.selectedTemplate = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setSelectedTemplate:self.selectedTemplate];
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"returnToNotes"]) {
        // do nothing special
    }
}
```

The segue identifier like "editTemplte" are set in storyboard by selecting the segue and using the attributes inspector to name them.